# Firebase Realtime Database, delete duplicate records

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Due to an error in my queue manager, my system ended up inserting the same record thousands of times in my realtime database. I was wondering if there is a way to delete duplicate records and keep just one?

See the print:

[image]

Comment: Sure, you can write code to delete child nodes that you don't want.  Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  I don't think it's going to get written for you.

Comment: Why don't you read the node you want. Then delete the top level node '632A9...' (which will delete everything in the node) and then write out the node you read in. That should be quick and painless.

Comment: @Jay is that after the correction was made, other data that should be at this level '632A9 ...' was included.

Comment: Right. that was the intention. Read the data you want to keep, delete the '632A9 ...' node and then write the data back out using the same node key '632A9 ...'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using to write data (cloud functions, mobile app), you need to run a one-off code to delete the existing data (assuming you fixed the error which wrote redundant data).

Seeing your database, the deletion code can follow this pseudo-code:

```
if(<node_parent> != <the_node_you_want_to_keep> 
  && <node_parent>/"Commentario" == <the_comment_that_got_repeated>
  && <node_parent>/"CodUsario" == "1")
    delete node
```

You can compare different fields to ensure only the duplicate data gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to read in the data you want to keep, then delete the entire node and then write out that kept data.

In other words, you know the top level path `632A9...` and the child `-MLrf6...` node you want. So read in the child node at `-MLrf6...'` then delete the top level node `632A9...` which in one commands does what your asking. Then simply write back out the data

```
let ref = your_firebase.child("632A9...").child("-MLrf6...")
ref.setData(the child data that was read in before deleting)
```